# Specifying ID in Mysqli query in php

Tags: php, mysqli, where-clause

I'm working on a CMS site, I've got blog posts that I store in a database. I can create, edit and delete them. There's an issue though when I want to edit them.
I can't specify the WHERE clause in the update query to match the id of the blog post I'm trying to edit!

Suppose I've got a blog post with an id of '5'.
If I write this code for it, it works exactly the way it should.

```
 $sqledit = "UPDATE paginas SET message='$_POST[message]' WHERE id= $_POST[id]";
```

But I don't want to edit just blog post #5, I want to edit the blog post that I'm updating. It seems to me this should work,

```
WHERE id= $_POST[id]";
```

... but it doesn't.

That just throws me an undefined id error. But it shouldn't because I can delete blog posts the exact same way with this particular code:

```
$sqldel = "DELETE FROM `paginas` WHERE id= $_POST[id]";
```

This does allow me to.

The code below is on the blog page, the edit query is in its own edit.php page

```
        if (isset($_POST['edit'])) // if pressed, execute

        {  
        echo

        '<br><br>  <div class="blogscript">
         <form action="edit.php" method="post">Edit your stuff<br>          
        <input type="text" placeholder='. $pagetitle . ' ><br><br>          
        <textarea id="message2" name="message">&lt;p&gt;' . $message . '&lt;/p&gt;</textarea><br>           
        <input type="submit" name="editsubmit" value="Confirm" />
        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="' . $id . '">.            </form></div>';
        }
```

I look forward to any tips I should try out.

EDIT:

**This is my edit.php page**

```
<?php
  $DB_host = "localhost";
  $DB_user = "root";
  $DB_pass = "";
  $DB_name = "cmsbase";

  $MySQLi_CON = new MySQLi($DB_host,$DB_user,$DB_pass,$DB_name);

     if($MySQLi_CON->connect_errno)
     {
         die("ERROR : -> ".$MySQLi_CON->connect_error);
     }


     $sql = "UPDATE paginas SET message='$_POST[message]' WHERE id= $_POST[id]";

    if ($MySQLi_CON->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "";
    } else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $MySQLi_CON->error;
    }
    $MySQLi_CON->close(); //close connection


    echo "<script>alert('Edited');location.href='index.php';</script>";

?>
```

EDIT: This is what the var_dump contains
[image: This is what the var_dump says]

Comment: Dunno if it was typo or not, should be $_POST['id'] with quote?

Comment: You should show us more of your PHP code. The edit.php page, to be exact.

Comment: This method of inserting variables is both error prone (as you have experienced) and vulnerable to SQL injection. Use a [prepared statement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead.

Comment: `'$_POST['id']'` would do fine. But there could be some other errors in your code. And I would recommend to store $_POST['id'] in a variable and then use it in the prepared query

Comment: I don't see any form control named `id`. Did I overlook it?

Comment: @HendraNucleo not if it's meant to be in a double-quoted string.

Comment: @Don'tPanic Ahh you right, again double quote. So the question is, where the 'id' coming from? didnt see form field had name 'id'. Or where it taken from?, obviously $_POST[id] is null ?

Comment: Do I need to give the form a name of 'id'?

Comment: Of course you need to provide a unique identifier to php code for recognizing which field need to updating or deleting. So my question is, what is $_POST[id] in your question above? and look at @Don'tPanic answer below.

Comment: $_POST[id] is now as it should the form that sets up the query, as shown in the above question with more code. I'm still not there yet, could use some more help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for values to be present in `$_POST`, you need to have some element (e.g. `<input>`, `<select>`, `<textarea>`) inside your form with a `name` attribute set to the `$_POST` key you want.

You can add a hidden input to your form for id.

```
<input type='hidden' name='id' value='" . $id . "'>
```

Assuming you are getting the `$message` variable shown in that form code by selecting from your database, you should be able to get the id from there as well, or potentially from your `$_GET` if that is how you determine which post is being displayed.

Comment: Yeah, the $message variable is selected from the database, the id to is simply its own field called id. I've tried what you did, this killed the error saying there was an undefined id, but it won't update. The conditional statement in my edit.php said it got edited, but it didn't. I used the $_POST method but neither $_POST nor $_GET are doing it for me :( 

I've updated the initial question with more code

Comment: It will not quite work the way you have it written in your updated code. Try replacing `value="\' . $id . \'">` with `value="' . $id . '">`. Escaping the single quotes prevent the value of the id variable from being concatenated into the string, so you're actually setting the name attribute to the string `' . $id . '`.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't do the trick either. I am supposed to keep the where clause like this, right?   WHERE id= $_POST[id]"; 
It doesn't throw me an error but it won't edit either.

Comment: Try `var_dump($_POST)` in edit.php to see what's really there.

Comment: I've updated the initial question with an image of what the var_dump contains. I hope you can make something out of it.

Comment: Well, yes. It looks like the $id variable is not defined when you use it in the hidden input. Before you use it there, it needs to be set to the id of the post you want to edit.

Comment: Ah, yeah. That finally did the trick. :) Now I've got a good little blog site going on. Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

> (While this is not actually an answer, what I want to say does not fit in the comments)

Your line

> ```
> $sql = "UPDATE paginas SET message='$_POST[message]' WHERE id= $_POST[id]";
> ```

Is horrific. This is the stuff of nightmares. Lets say that `POST`ed data in a form, is posted from a script from some robot somewhere, because I'm pretty sure you don't [prevent XSRF](http://blog.codinghorror.com/preventing-csrf-and-xsrf-attacks/) in your code.

What if that script chose to post:

```
$_POST ==> array => message = "mwahahaha";
                 => id      = "1; DROP TABLE paginas;"
```

And you may think "how would they know my table name?" ,but that's easily found from other nefarious id inserts or other hacks on your code from other entry points which give a SELECT result, and many tables have common names such as "*users*" / "*orders*" / "*baskets*" / "*touch-me*" etc. (Ok well maybe not touch-me, but you get the idea).

`Mysqli_real_escape_string()` Could be used but thats only escaping quote marks and special characters, it does not mitigate SQL injection and compromise.

**So, what should you do?**

In this instance I want to draw your attention to [PHP type juggling](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php). Unlike many other languages, PHP has implied data types rather than specific data tyes, so a data type of `"1.06"` can be `string` *and* juggled to being a `float` as well.

Your `id` parameter in your MySQL is very probably a numeric integer value, so how can you be sure that the value of `$_POST['id']` is also in integer rather than a [SQL Instruction](http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/sql-injection.html)?

```
$id = (int)$_POST['id'];
```

This *forces* the value to be an integer, so

```
$id = (int)"1; DROP TABLE paginas;";
```

Is actually processed as `$id = 1`. Therefore saving you lots of compromised tables, spam rows and other nefarious rubbish all over your website, your database and your reputation.

Please take the following concept on board:

***NEVER EVER TRUST ANY USER SUBMITTED CODE.***

***EVER***

Comment: Not a direct answer, but I'll take it! Thanks for your heads up, I will definitely reflect on what you said the next time I post my code here, and be wary of other people's code.

Comment: it's not about posting your code *here*, its about how your code checks that only valid data is submitted in forms. by the user.  @JohnMichael . Be wary of anyone filling in any form on a website you run, don't trust them! :-D